# How to select the page range to print in Windows 8 Modern UI apps?

Tags: windows-8, printing

Today I wanted to print an email from the Mail app (modern UI).

I selected devices from the charms bar, and I chose my printer. The problem is that it was a very long email (a 40 replies unthreaded email), and I only needed the first page.

It looks like there is no way to select a page range in the simple printing dialog, am I right?

I solved the problem by inserting just one page in the printer and then deleting the job, but this is not a real fix... (I could print to a PDF printer, then open in Acrobat and print again, but...)

Comment: This would have to be added by Microsoft in the case of the Mail application.

Comment: but it looks like it's a standard dialog. There is no page range textbox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's indeed the Mail App that needs to support printing ranges. You can see [how it would/should be implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700387.aspx) on MSDN. This means the Mail App doesn't support this (yet). The Mail App is still rather uncomplete at the moment, but maybe it will be added later. For now, there isn't really a solution, apart from what you're already doing or checking other mail apps (Metro or not).

Comment: For doing this they should place a "print" button, or it can be done easily from the charms bar?

Comment: Well, I'd have to look into the code and the documentation. But from what I can gather, they need to add the option in code, by which they're saying to the system: "hey, we support printing ranges". Plus, they have to write code to handle the case where the user selects this option. This means they have to write code so the system know what it means to print pages 3-7. As you can imagine, this could be different for text, images, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How to select the page range to print in Windows 8 Modern UI apps?
-This function is NOT supported in the Windows 8.0 or Windows 8.1 Modern UI Mail app.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to the Start tiles
2. Select the desktop window
3. Click on the E at the bottom of the page.
4. You can then go on AOL and get an old fashioned home page.

All the print functions will work just like they used to.

Comment: This does not answer the question.